# Child selector and ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I just don't really understand why an ID is not a valid parent:
http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Valid:

```
$("#listequestions tr").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("success");
});
```

Not valid:

```
$("#listequestions > tr").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("success");
});
```

Can somebody help me to understand why?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well ?

Comment: ">" indicates (the first level) immediate children while the other one  indicates all decendents

Comment: Is the tr an immediate child of #listequestions

Comment: *"I just don't really understand why an ID is not a valid parent"* What makes you think an ID isn't a valid parent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `tbody` is automatically inserted in a table if there is none.

That's why the only possible way to match `"#listequestions > tr"` would be to give the id to a `thead`, a `tfoot` or a `tbody`.

That's one of the perils of the child selector.

Let's suppose you have the following HTML :

```
<table id=listequestions>
    <tr><td>some text</td></tr>
</table>​
```

Then the `tr` would be matched by those two queries :

- `$('#listequestions > tbody > tr')`
- `$('#listequestions tr')`

Answer (score 1):

Here you are selecting the direct child inside the element with id listequestions

```
$("#listequestions > tr").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("success");
});
```

and here you are selecting all elements inside element with id listequestions which includes sub childs.

```
$("#listequestions tr").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("success");
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#listequestions  tr")
```

Will try to match `all the children which are tr`

```
$("#listequestions > tr")
```

Will match `only the immediate children`..

So if tr is not the immediate child then the second will not work..

As dystroy pointed out

Answer (score 0):

Would this work instead?

```
$("#listequestions").children("tr").click(function() {
      $(this).addClass("success");
    });
```

Comment: I don't think it's being deprecated. jQuery docs says the `$('parent > child', **context**)` selector will be, but not the regular `'parent > child'` one.

Comment: @RémiBreton: I misspoke and have corrected my statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#listequestions").find("tr").click(function() {
      $(this).addClass("success");
});
```